# Universal Windows App with MS SQL Server

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light

I'm going to create a POS application in uwp with MVVM light
i have the same project in WPF Entity Framework with SQL Server. Can i use the same database of MS SQL server instead of SQL lite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot connect to a remote SQL Server database directly from a UWP app. You need to consume the database through a service layer: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-access-data-from-935e360c

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new Entity Framework Core you can choose if you want to use MS SQL server in your project or the SQL Lite database. Its your choice.